# Brownian Motion and Progressive Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion. Define sign function as follows. $sign(0) = 0$ and $sign(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}, \forall x \neq 0$. I do not know how to show the following two questions, especially on the progressive measurability one. Could anyone provide some detailed explanation on how to go about with them, please? Thank you!

1. Show that $sign(B_t)$ is a progressive process.
2. Show that $sign(B_t)\cdot B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: $sign(B_t)B_t = |B_t|$, so it's always non negative, how can it be a Brownian motion?

Comment: @LiuGang Sorry, I thought wrong. The question used $\cdot$ which clearly not the usual multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct way to show that the process $X$ defined by $X_t=\mathrm{sign}(B_t)$ is progressively measurable is to consider, for every positive integer $n$, $$X^n_t=\frac{nB_t}{\sqrt{1+n^2B_t^2}}.$$ Each process $X^n$ is adapted with continuous paths hence progressively measurable. Furthermore, for every $t$, $X^n_t\to X_t$ almost surely, when $n\to\infty$, hence $X$ is progressively measurable.

(This answers item 1. Item 2. is absurd, for example because $X_tB_t=|B_t|$ and $t\mapsto E(|B_t|)$ is not constant hence $|B|$ is not a Brownian motion (much more is known but this simple argument suffices).)

Comment: As for item 2. I think there is contradiction. On one hand Brownian motion is a martingale and |B| is not. On the other hand, however, as Liu pointed out, sign(B)B = |B|. That is, given a sample path, we reflect the negative part. Then by strong Markov property and/or reflection principle, we should expect |B| to be a Brownian motion.

Comment: We should not expect |B| to be a Brownian motion. Not at all.

Comment: Thanks. I got reflection principle wrong. Reflection principle is not about only reflecting negative part.